# How to control the galvanometer scanner and XYZ stage to work synchronously via software?

Tags: control, laser, algorithm

I have a laser galvo scanners and XYZ stages. They are controlled separately by a servo control card and a galvanometer control card, and each performs well when working alone.

Now I want to combine them for hybrid interpolation and large-area marking. I know that there is a control card on the market that integrates the servo axis and the galvanometer axis, but I do not plan to buy a new control card for the time now.

Maybe there are some stitching algorithms available? Is there an open source solution to do this?

Comment: This is called mosaic imaging and there is an enormous amount of software (both open source and commercial) and thousands of academic papers, usually in the context of laser scanning microscopy. The challenge will be figuring out what is compatible with your existing hardware and software. You should definitely describe that in a lot more detail, or else hit up Google scholar and start reading papers.

Comment: It is also not clear to me if you are asking for software to control the galvo scanners and motor (e.g. scan image or thor image) or you already have that and are looking for software to stitch the frames (image composite editor, bigstitcher, etc). The more detail you give the better.

Comment: Thanks. I use scanlab rtc4 to control the galvanometer system, implementing some simple laser marking functions through the DLL interface called. At the same time, I used the SPiiPlus SC-LT 4-axis controller card produced by ACS to operate the xyz stage.I didn't have the software, just called the vendor's DLL library through C++

Comment: Edit that information into your question so it's clear what you're really asking. If you're developing everything from scratch in c++, you could either switch to an existing software platform that supports mosaic imaging, or add an image, move, image, move... Loop to your software. Then use image stitching software to stitch your frames together. Does that sound right? I can write up a more detailed answer if so.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn how to develop laser marking software. What has been implemented is simply the execution of G-code generated by existing CAM software via the rtc4 galvanometer system. But it can only engrave very small marks, and if the area is too large, the galvanometer will not work well. So I want to take the XYZ stage, engrave one part of the mark, and then move the stage and continue to engrave another part.

Comment: My comments above are for imaging, but if you're doing engraving none of that matters so disregard what I said. You should edit your question as well to make that clear.